# Custom Domain not working for serverless app

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy my express application which does server-side rendering for my react app using Serverless Framework. When I deploy it, it gives me a random generated url and it loads my app, although none of the static files load. So I'm trying to use a custom domain using [serverless-domain-manager](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager). But I can't get it to work. My DNS records are in Cloudflare so I created certificates in AWS Certificate Manager and succesfully connected it to my cloudflare records. I have also created a Hosted Zone for my domain. My serverless.yml file is like this:

```
service: sls-react-render
app: sls-react-render

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ca-central-1
  memorySize: 1024
  logRetentionInDays: 1
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: production

functions:
  server:
    handler: sls_dist/server.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}
custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
  customDomain:
    domainName: sls.domain.ca
    basePath: ''
    certificateName: sls.domain.ca
    certificateArn: arn:aws:acm:ca-central-1:xxxxx
    hostedZoneId: myHostedZoneId
    securityPolicy: tls_1_2
    stage: dev
    createRoute53Record: true
    endpointType: 'regional'

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: false

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
  - serverless-plugin-common-excludes
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-domain-manager
```

I deployed it, I ran `sls create_domain` and I can see my custom domain created in API Gateway and it's mapped to my lambda function. But when I go to my domain nothing loads however they random url generated by serverless loads the app. Any idea how I can figure out what's wrong? Here is the image of it deploying successfully:
[image]